# Google Charts убрать по оси y цифры

Tags: jquery, google-chart

Друзья, кто в курсе, как можно убрать на графике цифры слева по оси y и просто нарисовать вместо них вертикальную прямую черного цвета, аналогично линии по оси x?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>

google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart', 'line']
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawBasic);

function drawBasic() {

  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('number', '');
  data.addColumn('number', '');

  data.addRows([
    [2, 1],
    [5, 1],
    [8, 1],
    [10, 1],
    [11, 1],
    [14, 1],
    [17, 1],
    [18, 1],
    [22, 1],
    [25, 1],
    [27, 0.5],
    [28, 9],
    [29, 8],
    [30, 8],
  ]);

  var options = {
    colors: ['red'],
    pointSize: 7,
    dataOpacity: 0.7,
    pointShape: 'square',
    chartArea: {
      left: 30,
      top: 0,
      bottom: 20,
      width: '100%',
      height: '100%'
    },

    curveType: 'function',
    pointsVisible: true,
    tooltip: {
      trigger: 'selection'
    },
    legend: {
      position: 'none'
    },
    height: 250,
    hAxis: {
      gridlines: {
        color: 'transparent'
      }
    },
    vAxis: {
    //ticks: [0],
      gridlines: {
        count: 10,
        color: '#dddddd'
      }
    },
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',

  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));


  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
hAxis: {
  textPosition: 'none'
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]